# Waiting the driver until an element to disappear

Tags: java, selenium

While Automating the search functionality, enter some search key word and click on Search button, the results need to load in grid. It takes few seconds time to load and displaying "Loading..." text like this in fallowing div.

```
<div id="loadmask-1027-msgTextEl" class="x-mask-msg-text">Loading...</div>
```

How could I wait until this message disappear.

Answer (score 4):

Webdriver has built in waiting functionality you just need to build in the condition to wait for.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

   WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return (driver.findElements(By.id("xx")).isEmpty());
     }
   });
```

you will need to replace the *By.id("xx")* with however you identify the element you are expecting to go.

Comment: I would like to add that size() == 0 should be replaced with isEmpty()

Comment: isEmpty() doesn't return a WebElement

Answer (score 1):

This works with selenium 2.4.0 All of the other solution are bugged. The apply method can not return a boolean, it must return a WebElement. The API documentation is also incorrect. Here is the correct code.

```
final public static boolean waitForElToBeRemove(WebDriver driver, final By by) {
    try {
        driver.manage().timeouts()
                .implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(UITestBase.driver,
                DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

        boolean present = wait
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(by));

        return present;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        driver.manage().timeouts()
                .implicitlyWait(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually upvoted your answer because it is kind of correct. The problem with ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated is that it internally uses the implicit wait, not the wait that created it, so despite us using a fluent wait, if we call invisibilityOfElementLocated, we will be forced to wait an implicit wait, which is globally configured on the driver. So your solution, while not entirely, definitely doesn't deserve the hate it got.

Comment: lol, i actually recently replaced this with a JavaScript lookup, inside of a state machine. This runs much faster and works all the time. I found that all of these answers.. including mine.. do not work well all the time. Selenium does not like these type of checks and reports an unnecessary amount of pointless logs about how its not found yet.

Comment: Yes, we do the js lookup as well, but my point was your post provides the correctest solution (albeit, prone to threading issues), while all others failed to even influence the problem.

Comment: @baba well im glad you understood the code i posted.. Yes this code is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method where you will identify if the element is present. Put this logic in a loop and wait for a second before going to the next iteration. You can probably wait for 10 to 15 seconds before you break completely from the loop. If the element disappears then it will throw an exception. You can use try catch and within catch you can break the loop. This will ensure code actually waits for element to disappear or max 10 to 15 seconds.

Comment: When ever the 'loading...' disappear then only i can able to access. up to that i need to wait.

Comment: @SubbaraoGaddam I understand that. Use the method to identify if the element if present. Then wait for 1 second. Again identify if the element is present. IF the element is not present then an exception will be thrown. Catch this exception and within the catch block break the loop.Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please specify the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach in Java, without "wait"-methods of Selenium, if the current code-examples are not suitable solutions to you.
I'm using WebDriver with JUnit:

```
public void waitForElementToDisappear() throws InterruptedException{
//try for 5 seconds
for(int i=0;i<=5;++i){
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath(<elementExpectToDisappear>)).isEmpty()){
//here your code, if element finally disappeared
break;
}else{
Thread.sleep(1000);
}
if(i==5)
fail("element not disappeared within 5 seconds");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I used in kotlin and it worked:

```
wait?.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("progress_bar"))))
```