# Progress bar wait till it disappears

Tags: c#, automation, appium, winappdriver

I am using WinappDriver to automate desktop applications. I am having a "Please wait" progress bar with name locator="status" and i have added a wait statement to wait till this progress bar disappears as below :

```
public static void WaitUntilConditionIsMet(int timeoutInSeconds, string status )
        {
            var wait = new DefaultWait<WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>>(Session)
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds),
                PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
            };
            wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(InvalidOperationException));
            wait.Until(session =>
            {
                var elementUnderTest = Session.FindElementByName(status );
                return elementUnderTest==null;

            });
        }
```

But it is not working. Can anyone help me out in what other condition i can provide to make it happen?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why are you dependent of that progress bar? Could be more simple to implement your test if you put that WinForm to close after ProgressBar be full. On your test design you just need to wait till that WinForm disappear and verify (Assert).

Comment: please see my answer here  may it help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64209923/8660721